# Semantic web to develop suggesion search box using vb.net and MQL

Tags: vb.net, semantic-web, freebase, mql

am developing a suggestion search box through which user enter any keyword initials and get the suggestions as a down menu (Jquery).The data source I want to use is from Freebase database (freebase.com). I want to use vb.net and Metaweb Query Language (MQL) to get a semantic web project.

Any helpful links that enable me to finalize the project is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported the jQuery freebase search widget to Dart.
This might be easier for you to interpret if you are not fluent with jQuery.
see

- https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-widget
- https://github.com/bwu-dart/freebase_searchwidget_polymer/blob/master/lib/components/freebase_searchwidget.dart

If you want to use this for a web application anyway you can just use the jQuery search widget provided by Google (first link)